# how to implement tabstop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I know using tabindex="-1" we can skip the feild using `TAB` keyword .But I want to tab stop tab when it come to button.can there is tab stop event present .

Example in my case it focus to A (input field) --> Email (input field) --->button (sdfsdf) .Now I don't want to move to test input field using tab key word

here is code
https://jsfiddle.net/nz281b46/1/

```
Name: <input name="name"   />
Age: <input name="age" tabindex="-1"  />
Email: <input name="email"/>
<button>
sdfsdf
</button>
test: <input name="text"/>
```

I don't want to move next input or any field when focus come to button "sdfsdf"

Answer (score 0):

First add `class="tabdisabled"` to your button. Then you can simply use:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tabdisabled').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Additional Behaviour
        }
    });
});
```

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nz281b46/3/

Hope this helps! :)